# Force a connection to be closed after a period in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, httprequest

I have user `http.request` for making connection to another server in nodejs. Unfortunately that server has a delay in responding in some situations. So I want to close the request after some period.
I have found following code but this close connection if target server was not reachable or connection has not been established.

```
req.on('socket', function (socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(myTimeout);  
    socket.on('timeout', function() {
        req.abort();
    });
});
```

What I want is closing connection after for example 2 seconds wether data is coming or not.

Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know the sockets library you use, maybe it has some ready and nice solution for that as well, but it looks simple to just use `setTimeout` function:

```
req.on('socket', function (socket) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // maybe some additional condition here
        // or recursive call if you want to wait 2 more seconds
        // or whatever else
        // but if you want to just abort...
        req.abort();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Again, this maybe looks like a workaround, but it definitely should be enough as I understand from your request.